# Explode a $_POST input inside a class?

Tags: php, class, post, explode

I'm trying to manually reverse an array in PHP. The array is entered through a form, exploded and then reversed. I can get the code working without classes, but I am currently being taught about classes, so I'm trying to make my current code work with classes too.

```
<?php 
class reverseArray{

public function setSting(){
        $string = $_POST['numberInput'];
        return $string;

    }

public function explodeString(){
    $array = explode(' ', $string);
    return $array;
}

public function setArray(){
    $arrayToEcho = explodeString();
    return  $arrayToEcho;
}   


public function returnArray(){
    for ($i = count($arrayToEcho) - 1; $i >=0 ; $i--){
        echo  " ";
        $arrayToEcho[$i] = $arrayToEcho[$i];
        echo $arrayToEcho[$i];
    }
}
}
?>
```

I'm still very unsure if PHP classes and how to call on returns etc, so if someone could point me in the right direction? I currently get no errors or warnings, but also no output!

Comment: how does `$string` get in to the function\method `explodeString` ?

Comment: Either they aren't doing a good job teaching about classes, or you weren't listening, since you're missing a basic principle about them.

Comment: Don't forget about the built in `rsort()` function to reverse an array. More information can be found at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php.

Answer (score 1):

Looking up variable scopes will help you.  You need a class property in order to use it in other methods, or functions.  Right now, `$string` is only available inside the function it is defined at.  You can declare a class property and use the `$this` accessor.

```
class reverseArray{

    public $string;

    public function setString(){
        $this->string = $_POST['numberInput'];
        return $this->string;
    }

    public function explodeString(){
        $array = explode(' ', $this->string);
        return $array;
    }

}
```

I think a better usage for this class would be

```
    public function setString($str){
        $this->string = $str;
    }
```

This would allow this class to be re-used as you can use any string inside the class, not just `$_POST['numberInput']`

Comment: .. dont forget to call the class and setString (or move that in to the constructor) ..sting vs string also :-)